# Как рассчитать сложность алгоритма?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сложность

мне нужно рассчитать сложность данного алгоритма:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=2)
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
          operations++;
```

У меня получилось примерно это, но я не уверен в правильности:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первом равенстве ошибка.

Comment: Подумайте вот над какой штукой: как соотносится сложность алгоритма и значение `operations` в конце?

Comment: Эн-квадрат, что тут думать.

Comment: Откуда у вас взялся куб непонятно

Comment: Нужно именно рассчитать сложность, а не оценить

Comment: Ну очевидно что у вас ошибка, какое может быть «неуверен», если при очевидном эн-квадрат у вас в рассчёте куб получился. И я бы сказал что ошибка в самом первом выражении

Comment: А количество операций проще посчитать арифметической прогрессией. 0+2+4+…

Comment: Да что тут считать... внешний цикл — 2,4,...,n. Внутренний - именно такое количество раз:2,4,...,n. Суммируем арифметическую прогрессию — получим O(n^2).